# Subversion update misses new directories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion misses new directories during update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821983/subversion-misses-new-directories-during-update)

Periodically we have trouble with SVN when doing updates.  Very occasionally when someone adds a new directory doing an update through Tortoise doesn't work.  If we do a "Fully Recursive" update using "Update from revision..." option then it picks it up fine.

I'm poked around and seen [this question which is virtually identical but with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821983/subversion-misses-new-directories-during-update).  I've found the item on the SVN website, referenced by that post, that talks about an issue in 1.6.0 which is now fixed.  However my SVN version is 1.6.9 and Tortoise is 1.6.7 so I wouldn't expect to have this problem any more.

This only seems to occur with new directories, never seen it for individual files.

We may have had older versions of Tortoise at one point (can't remember which tho) so maybe some issue has been introduced into our repo that an upgrade doesn't solve.

We have the workaround but it wastes a few minutes of head-scratching after failed builds to figure it out and people who haven't come across this problem before really struggle until they ask someone else.

Anyone know if this is a known bug and any permanent solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: As stated in my question, I pointed out the question you've linked but it has no conclusive answer.

Comment: @MikeQ: Why did you make this a new question then instead of commenting on the question that already exists if it is about the same thing? Your question doesn't appear to have any significant differences? Anyway, there are answers on that question now, one of which is marked as correct.

Comment: The answer in that thread does not solve my problem.  I use the Fully Recursive "fix" when this problem does occur but it does not solve the problem going forward, it will happen again in the future.